GA4 Google analytics: проблемы проблемы с отображением активности пользователя в User Explorer
Я столкнулся с проблемой отображения активности пользователя в User Explorer GA4 при использовании пользовательского идентификатора пользователя.
Вот сценарий проблемы: когда я использую собственный идентификатор пользователя для идентификации пользователей, они отображаются в User Explorer. Однако при попытке отобразить их активность я получаю сообщение об ошибке «не удалось загрузить данные для этого компонента».


